# Is there a way to find sql result in following json format?

Tags: php, json, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables tblOne and tblTwo. 
tblOne Table contains values like

```
**Id Amount TotalReceipt**
1  1000   2
2  2000   3
```

tblTwo Table contains values like

```
**Id tblOneId ReceiptNo**
1  1        001
2  1        002
3  2        003
4  2        004
5  2        005
```

is there any way to get result in following json format:

```
{
{
"Id":"1",
"Amount":"1000",
"TotalReceipt":"2",
"ReceiptDetail":[
            {"Id":"1","tblOneId":"1","ReceiptNo":"001"},
            {"Id":"2","tblOneId":"1","ReceiptNo":"002"}
            ]
},
{
"Id":"2",
"Amount":"2000",
"TotalReceipt":"3",
"ReceiptDetail":[
            {"Id":"3","tblOneId":"2","ReceiptNo":"003"},
            {"Id":"4","tblOneId":"2","ReceiptNo":"004"},
            {"Id":"5","tblOneId":"2","ReceiptNo":"005"}
            ]
}
}
```

Comment: Why can't you do this in php?

Comment: This can be done with [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Have you looked at [`FOR JSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: @Larnu yeah i took a look but it doesnt support in sql 2012.

Comment: I've added the tag to your post then, so that any future readers know this. This does mean, however, that the version of SQL Server you have doesn't support creating JSON (natively). Personally, I would look to do this in PHP now, as it'll be far harder to do you SQL Server without out of the box functionality. if you can't do this in PHP, then respond to Salmon A's comment asking "Why?".

Comment: @Larnu PHP side it can be done but i thought if there is a way then give it a consideration. BTW Thanks, going for PHP side manipulation.